Implementing vuefire - module parse failed Unexpected token (80:52)
I'm trying to convert from auth0 to Firebase App, with vuefire.
I have followed this guide: https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html
But when trying to run the service, I get this error:
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (80:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| }
| function checkWrittenTarget(data, fnName) {
>   if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data, "data")?.get?.() === data) {
|     console.warn(`[VueFire] the passed "options.target" is already the returned value of "${fnName}". If you want to subscribe to a different data source, pass a reactive variable to 
"${fnName}" instead:
| https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/realtime-data.html#declarative-realtime-data

I'm have the following in my package file:
[...]
"firebase": "^9.23.0",
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"vuefire": "^3.1.23",
[...}

Any idea what's wrong here?

It looks like its due to the usage of optional chaining, I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662540/13617497

This is very specific to your project setup, which is unknown

Could it be due to fact that I might be using an older version of vue-cli 4.x?

Yes why are you using Webpack rather than Vite here?
